# How do I scope nuxt-link-exact-active only for particular page in nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I am creating a side menu bar, and I want to highlight name of page user is currently active on. Something like this:
[image: screenshot of side menu]

I have successfully managed to do that, but style I defined is taking effect on all the links throughout the website, which is causing a lot of problem.

If I apply `<style scoped>`, style is not taking effect anywhere. Not even on intended page.

My Component looks something like this..

***Menubar.vue***

```
<template>
    <ul class="w-56 border bg-base-100 border-none">
        <li class="my-4">
            <nuxt-link active-class="current-dash-page" to="./general" class="nav-link p-3">General Information</nuxt-link>
        </li>
        <li class="my-6">
            <nuxt-link to="./announcements" class="p-3">Announcements</nuxt-link>
        </li>
        <li class="my-6">
            <nuxt-link to="./learners" class="p-3">Manage Learners</nuxt-link>
        </li>
        <li class="my-6">
            <nuxt-link to="./schedule" class="p-3">Schedule</nuxt-link>
        </li>
        <li class="my-6">
            <nuxt-link to="./danger" class="p-3">Danger Zone</nuxt-link>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

```
<style>
.nuxt-link-exact-active {
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    background-color: hsla(var(--a) / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You could make the CSS selector more specific with something like `.my-cool-class .nuxt-link-exact-active` I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the values of your to="" arguments. They are relative to the current page, so if you navigate to, for example, "learners" then your url will end with .../learners/ then if you navigate to "danger" your url will change to .../learners/danger/ which will be missed by the exact-active class. Try giving absolute values to to="".

Answer (score 0):

The css class you should be using is router-link-exact-active